# Can mp3 data be read from the iPhone music library?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I hate asking stupid questions but I swear I looked through all [the documentation regarding the iPod Library access](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Audio/Conceptual/iPodLibraryAccess_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html).

I'm hoping maybe there's a lower level API that I can rock to bust out the solution. Anyways, I really wanted to make a crowd DJing app where users can pick a song and place it in a queue at a party, but I can't find any way to access the mp3 data of the iPhone music library, which is kind of what the idea is predicated on.

If the answer is a flat out "NO", leave a comment, that way I have the liberty of deleting the question :).

**--EDIT--**

The "data" that I want to read is the actual meat of the file, as in the part that's fun to listen to. Not the name or the genre or anything...

Comment: Given that [Ecoute's](http://pixiapps.com/ecouteios/) current version is entirely based on the device's media library, including iTunes Match songs, there's *some* way of doing it (source: [MacStories review](http://www.macstories.net/reviews/ecoute-2-review/)). However, as I don't know obj-c, I can't help you there.

Comment: Thank you, looks like I'm getting somewhere

Comment: Before you go to far with this, I would contact a lawyer familiar with intellectual property law. I think it might be illegal to make a "Crowd DJ" app. Playing music to a crowd requires special licensing, it's not enough to just own a copy of the music. As an app developer, you can be held liable for copyright infringement by your customers.

Comment: @AbhiBeckert thanks abhi, I do have an IP lawyer on hand if need be, but I typically take a "cross that bridge" approach

Answer (score 1):

It's not exactly clear on which `data` you want to read, although the standard way of accessing iPhone, or iPod music libraries is to use:

**[MPMusicPlayerController Class](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMusicPlayerController_ClassReference/Chapters/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008221)**, which is part of the **[Media Player Framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MediaPlayer_Framework/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006952)**.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**, you can. In a limited way.

With the *Media Player Framework* you query for the songs and ask for key `MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL` which returns `NSURL`. Then with *AVFoundation Framework* you create `AVURLAsset` and you can access all tracks and their audio content. <strike>Maybe it's even possible to create `NSData` from this URL.</strike>

**Update:** From the docs:

> **`MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL`**
>   A URL pointing to the media item, from which an `AVAsset` object (or other URL-based AV Foundation object) can be created, with any options as desired. Value is an `NSURL` object.
>   The URL has the custom scheme of `ipod-library`. For example, a URL might look like this:
>
> ```
> ipod-library://item/item.m4a?id=12345
> ```
>
> **Usage of the URL outside of the AV Foundation framework is not supported.**

Maybe you can create the `AVURLAsset` and read the buffers and write them to a file…

Comment: Do think you could post a sample of how you would extract the data from a song in the itunes library to a `NSString`, or some other way of uploading to a webserver?

Comment: @BrianWheeler I was thinking about this today. I didn't try opening the URL using `NSData`, only `AVURLAsset`. That's why I used word _maybe_. I really think if this would be possible, there already would be some apps exporting iPod library out of the device.